# Equation of a Magnetic Flux Line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

I have a simple problem that I am not quite sure how approach:

> Consider a spatially nonuniform magnetostatic field expressed in terms of a Cartesian coordinate system by
>
> $\textbf{B}(x,z) = B_0[\alpha z\hat{x} + (1 +\alpha x)\hat{z}]$
>
> Determine the equation of a magnetic flux line.

I assume that the answer will be some line in the (x,z) plane, but I am not quite sure how to do the calculation; it seems I am missing something obvious. A quick calculation shows that this magnetic field does satisfy Maxwell's:

$
\nabla \times \textbf{B} = 0
$

$
\nabla \cdot \textbf{B} = 0
$

(There is no **J** or $\frac{\partial\textbf{E}}{\partial t}$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnetic flux lines are a useful concept for visualization, but in my opinion should not be taken too seriously (in other words, I would not consider it especially useful to compute magnetic flux lines).

But I understand the question as follows: You have to find equation for "integrals" of the field, that is curves, where the magnetic field is tangential at each point. As the magnetic field has no sources or sinks those lines will never intersect.

So the differential equation for the flux lines will be $\dot{\vec r}(s) = \vec B\big(\vec r(s)\big)$ (and from this you can easily get the general solution).

Comment: If I use a Cartesian coordinate system, what does the dot on $\dot{\vec{r}}(s)$ represent? What is the form of $\dot{\vec{r}}(s)$?

Comment: $\vec r$ is just a position vector, $s$ is an arbitrary coordinate along the flux line and the dot signifies the derivative with respect to $s$.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer to include a sample system of equations to solve? If if solve the flux line that @kctx mentioned then I end up with a circle, but when I try to solve the equations below I end up with real exponentials which can't possibly be a circle, what is going on here?

<space>

$
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{ds} &= B_0 \alpha z\\
\frac{dz}{ds} &= B_0[1+\alpha x]\\
\end{align}
$

Comment: From those equations we actually get this system:

$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2x}{ds^2} &=B_0^2\alpha[1+\alpha x]\\
\frac{d^2z}{ds^2} &=(B_0 \alpha)^2 z
\end{align}$

Comment: I believe @kctx's answer to mean that from $z = 0$, $x = 0$ you get a flux line of the form $x = 0$, $z \in \mathbb{R}$, on that $\vec B$ is constantly equal to $B_0 \hat z$.

Comment: Hey, so I think that the correct way to go about this is to solve the following the set of differential equations generate by: $d\vec{s}|B/ds| = \vec{B}$, where $d\vec{s} = dx\hat{x} + dy\hat{y} + dz\hat{z}$, and $\vec{B} = B_x\hat{x} + B_y\hat{y} + B_z\hat{z}$

Comment: And in dependence on what parameter will you give the curve? (Furthermore, this should give the same curves as my equations, just in another parametrization).

Comment: You are right. If I divide the first two equations for dx/ds and dz/ds to write dx/dz, and I separate variables and integrate both sides I obtain curves for Hyperbolas in the (x,z) plane, which is the expected behavior. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Any flux line seems ok,  From x=0, z=0.  The flux line would same magnitude of B=B0

Comment: So you are saying that the magnitude of **B** along a magnetic flux line is constant?

Comment: Not in general, but along the one pointed out.